# How to auto start Xserver after boot?

Tags: boot, unity, login, xorg, xserver

I was "Desktop Environment Hopping" and I broke the Unity DE in ubuntu. I have reinstalled the unity desktop. But ubuntu is not entering into login screen gui or gnome shell gui after boot.

I am able to enter into Unity Gnome GUI after logging into tty and manually starting Xserver using the following command.

`startx`

How do I get back my login screen and get my Xserver and GUI to start automatically after boot.

Comment: I'd check if there is a login screen to get to. It should be `lightdm` or `gdm3`, and if either is installed, it should show in the output of `dpkg -l | grep 'gdm\|lightdm'`.

Comment: Thanks, there was an issue with display manager. Selecting gdm3 display manager with the following command solved the issue.

```sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by reconfiguring the display manager.

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`